# What should timeout first (ALB or Server)

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-services, networking, load-balancing

We have a server and an ALB, I was wondering what is the best practice for request timeouts.

Currently we have it configured such:

- ALB request timeout is 120sec
- Server request timeout is 115sec

My gut tells me that the server should timeout first so the server has control of how to respond to the client, but wanted to see if there is any best practice when it comes to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My gut tells me that the server should timeout first so the server has control of how to respond to the client

This is absolutely how I would do it. Leave the ALB timeouts for instances like when your server has stopped responding due to a crash or something.